# Ubuntu 13.10 with Cinnamon Desktop Environment

Tags: 13.10, shutdown, menu, cinnamon

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10 and added the Cinnamon Desktop Environment and I noticed that the restart and shutdown buttons are MISSING!  Only Suspend and Cancel are there.  In Ubuntu 13.04 with the Cinnamon Desktop Environment, everything is there and works!  Why are the restart and shutdown buttons showing in 13.04 but not 13.10???

Comment: I intended to use Cinnamon on my HP Netbook and PC with 13.10. On both, the Cinnamon desktop refuses to respond to mouse clicks! I used `Ctrl-Alt-F2`, logged in and did `sudo apt-get remove cinnamon` and `sudo apt-get autoremove` and shifted back to the original `lightdm` environment!

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behavior. To show the shutdown menu for example, change the setting for the respective button:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power 'interactive'
```